# Python: Trouble with Encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am saving my data into a dictionary and after saving it to the dictionary I printed the data to see what it looks like and I see the unicode:

```
(u'520775', [[u'Kategori:2. divisjon fotball for herrer 2008']])
(u'754686', [[u'Kategori:Debutalbum', u'Kategori:Musikkalbum fra 1990', u'Kategori:Tre Sm\xe5 Kinesere-album']])
(u'381191', [[u'Kategori:Serierundene i Adeccoligaen 2007']])
(u'972597', [[u'Kategori:Tippeligaen 2011']])
(u'263001', [[u'Kategori:Musikkalbum fra 2003']])
(u'23037', [[u'Kategori:Luftforsvaret']])
(u'640060', [[u'Kategori:Deltagermedaljen', u'Kategori:F\xf8dsler i 1923', u'Kategori:Norske folkemusikere', u'Kategori:Norske trekkspillere', u'Kategori:Paul Harris Fellow', u'Kategori:Personer fra Vefsn kommune']])
```

I have the following code, I used the format option but it didn't really work. What also confuses me is,when I print the id prior to saving it in dictionary, I see it without integer.

Here is the segment of the code,

```
for (pageId, pageData) in data['query']['pages'].iteritems():
            categoryTitles = [];
            idTitleDictionary[pageId] = [];
            print pageId;
            try:
                for category in pageData['categories']:
                    categoryTitles.append(category['title']);
                idTitleDictionary[format(pageId)].append(categoryTitles);
```

I am trying it figure how to encode it prior to saving it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `print` a `dict`, or `list`, or `tuple`, `repr` is called on the items in the container, rather than `str` like when you `print` them directly, so you see the unicode escape codes.

If you were to

```
mydict = dict(((u'520775', [[u'Kategori:2. divisjon fotball for herrer 2008']]),
(u'754686', [[u'Kategori:Debutalbum', u'Kategori:Musikkalbum fra 1990', 
              u'Kategori:Tre Sm\xe5 Kinesere-album']]),
(u'381191', [[u'Kategori:Serierundene i Adeccoligaen 2007']]),
(u'972597', [[u'Kategori:Tippeligaen 2011']]),
(u'263001', [[u'Kategori:Musikkalbum fra 2003']]),
(u'23037', [[u'Kategori:Luftforsvaret']]),
(u'640060', [[u'Kategori:Deltagermedaljen', u'Kategori:F\xf8dsler i 1923', 
              u'Kategori:Norske folkemusikere', 
              u'Kategori:Norske trekkspillere', u'Kategori:Paul Harris Fellow', 
              u'Kategori:Personer fra Vefsn kommune']])))

for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    print key,
    for elem in value[0]:
        print elem + ',',
    print
```

You'd see the strings encoded properly for your terminal. You don't need to do anything to those strings to interpret the escape codes -- everything is stored properly, it's just how it's being displayed.

Comment: So this means I can go on with my business because I plan to use the data in the dictionary to make some sql queries. These data were collected from an api. Thats why I was concerned.

Comment: Thanks mate I tried a simple example on the terminal great, and thanks for the excellent fast answer, here is my example:
>>> mydict = {}
>>> pageId = 12345
>>> mydict[pageId] = []
>>> mydict
{12345: []}
>>> mydict[pageId].append(['Category1', 'Category2']
... )